# Need help on basic Qt structure

Tags: qt

Hi I am a Qt beginner. I want to make something like a column of icons on the left, after click the icons different forms and results appear on the right, how can I do this? Should I choose `QMainWindow` or `QWidget` for this project?

Answer (score 0):

> should I choose mainwindow or widget for this
>   project?

If what you described are the only things present in the window, you should use a QMainWindow.  If you think you will want to re-use this arrangement in the future, I'd use a QWidget.  It will probably be easier to implement each set of forms as a separate QWidget (in Designer; if you're building the GUI programmatically, just add the forms to a QLayout in a QFrame).

> a column of icons on the left, after click the icons different
>   forms and results appear on the right

For the column of icons, you should look at QListWidget.  It provides a vertical list of QListWidgetItems, and the items can contain icons, and nothing else.  Your main window can then connect to the list widget's `currentItemChanged` signal (or `itemChanged` or something else; there are several choices), and modify the forms in the right-hand side of the window appropriately.